# Varnish Restart Trace

Tags: restart, varnish, varnish-vcl

Our Varnish Instance

```
 /usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run/varnish.pid -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/cm-varnish.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 1h -u varnish -g varnish -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,24G -p shm_reclen 10000 -p http_req_hdr_len 10000 -p thread_pool_add_delay 2 -p thread_pools 8 -p thread_pool_min 500 -p thread_pool_max 4000 -p sess_workspace 1073741824
```

32G Ram, 16 Core Processor and We allocate 24GB of memory for varnish

Average uptime of our varnish instance remains 3hrs which is very much low. Our Cache TTL is 1Hr and Grace time is 2Hrs. Every 5 min once we generally refresh the cache contents [with more than n hits] through a java process. We track hits of varnish by constanly polling `varnishncsa` output.

I tried `varnishadm panic.show`

```
Last panic at: Thu, 23 May 2013 09:14:42 GMT
Assert error in WSLR(), cache_shmlog.c line 220:
  Condition(VSL_END(w->wlp, l) < w->wle) not true.
thread = (cache-worker)
ident = Linux,2.6.18-238.el5,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit,epoll
Backtrace:
  0x42dc76: /usr/sbin/varnishd [0x42dc76]
  0x432d1f: /usr/sbin/varnishd(WSLR+0x27f) [0x432d1f]
  0x42a667: /usr/sbin/varnishd [0x42a667]
  0x42a89e: /usr/sbin/varnishd(http_DissectRequest+0xee) [0x42a89e]
  0x4187d1: /usr/sbin/varnishd(CNT_Session+0x741) [0x4187d1]
  0x42f706: /usr/sbin/varnishd [0x42f706]
  0x3009c0673d: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3009c0673d]
  0x30094d40cd: /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x30094d40cd]
```

Any inputs on what do we miss?

Comment: Have you tried running varnish with default advanced values? I mean without `-p shm_reclen 10000 -p http_req_hdr_len 10000 -p thread_pool_add_delay 2 -p thread_pools 8 -p thread_pool_min 500 -p thread_pool_max 4000 -p sess_workspace 1073741824`

Comment: We chose this value based on http://kly.no/posts/2010_01_26__Varnish_best_practices__.html does this have anything to do with the assertion

Comment: That post is quite old (refers to Varnish 2.x AFAIK) and clearly states "Tune based on necessity". For me, first thing when debugging/tracing this kind of issues is stick to the default config.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have a very long cookie string (or other custom headers) so that it overflows the http_req_hdr_len. I remember reading something about such a bug that was fixed but afaik not released in a stable version. I'm afraid I don't have better sources than my own memory at hand.

You also have a very high sess_workspace and total number of threads possible. That does less for performance than it does in risking swapping in most setups.